# "Cannot invoke JavaScript outside of a WebView context" error when running Javascript in Blazor Hybrid

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, maui-blazor

I'm trying to use `IJsruntime` for importing a `.js` file to use in Blazor Hybrid (use in the razor component).

**The service:**

```cs
public class InitialDocumentHtmlService : IInitialDocumentHtmlService
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime runtime;

    public InitialDocumentHtmlService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        this.runtime = jsRuntime;

    }

    public async Task<string> GetColorAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {

// here u get exeption
        var helloword = await runtime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", token,
            "./test.js");

        await helloword.InvokeVoidAsync("helloWorld", token);

    }
}
```

**test.js:**

```js
export function helloWorld() {
    console.log("Hello");
    alert("hello");
}
```

However, it's only working in Blazor WebAssembly, while I get the following in Blazor Hybrid:

**Exception:**

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Services.WebViewJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(long, string, string, Microsoft.JSInterop.JSCallResultType, long) in WebViewJSRuntime.cs
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<TValue>(long, string, System.Threading.CancellationToken, object[])
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<TValue>(string, System.Threading.CancellationToken, object[])
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeAsync<TValue>(Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime, string, System.Threading.CancellationToken, object[])
Datanex.Frontend.App.Modules.Services.InitialDocumentHtmlService.GetColorAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken) in InitialDocumentHtmlService.cs
Datanex.Frontend.App.Modules.Services.InitialApp.InitAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken) in InirialApp.cs
Datanex.Frontend.App.Component.Pages.Login.OnInitializedAsync() in Login.razor
```

**Message:**

> Cannot invoke JavaScript outside of a WebView context.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can run run javascript in blazor hybrid successfully.

The Service Class:

```
namespace MauiApp3
{
    public class MyService
    {
        public IJSRuntime js;
        public MyService(IJSRuntime js)
        {
            this.js = js;
        }
        public async Task<string> Test(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var hello = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",token, "./test.js");
            await hello.InvokeVoidAsync("helloword");
            return "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

The Razor Page:

```
@page "/counter"
@inject IJSRuntime js;
@using MauiApp3
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        MyService myService = new MyService(js);
        string value = await myService.Test(new CancellationToken());
    }
}
```

And the structure of my project:

[image]

Comment: Did you add the js file in the project's index.html? And you can refer to this case [that has the same error as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611422/blazor-maui-issue-when-calling-javascript-method-from-component-class-library-s). @madiyyarrrr